# Java Applet won't start

Tags: java, applet, noclassdeffounderror, buildpath

I've developed Java Applet application, but I'm having problems with deployment. Application successfully compiled in Eclipse. I exported application in a JAR file. I've created HTML file and put following in it:

```
<html>
<title>The Hello, World Applet</title>
    <body>
        <hr>
            <applet code="Applet.class" width="100%" height="100%" archive="Clijent.jar" >
            <

            </applet>
        <hr>
    </body>
</html>
```

When I start applet using web browser, I get following error.

[image]

I successfully find that class in my Eclipse project, and I added it to the build path. Where is the problem?

Comment: post your launch class and error Details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the SwingX [`swingx.jar`](http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/pub/mirrors/maven2/org/swinglabs/swingx/0.9.2/swingx-0.9.2.jar) to class list in the Applet's `archive` attribute in the applet tag so that it is included in the classpath

```
<applet code="Applet.class" width="100%" height="100%" archive="Clijent.jar,swingx.jar" >
```

Comment: You helped me, this was solution. Thank you very much :)